# I need to fire key events to a SWF, in a browser, using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

So, I've got an idea flowing and I need to fire keyboard events to an embedded swf on a webpage (in Chrome).

And I'm dealing with some limitations:

- The input events have to come from javascript
- The events need to be fired to a swf
- I do not have access to the source of the swf

How I get this done, doesn't really matter. It's more of a personal project, so it can have as many loopholes as I wish.

I've investigated firing directly from javascript, but I concluded that this is simply not possible. Does anyone else have any ideas? Could I for example use the Win32 API somehow?

Comment: Ideally you would have the source to the swf and use [ExternalInterface](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/external-interface/) to pass call an actionscript function with the keys as parameters from javascript based on the captured keyevents. A hacky idea that comes to mind is to create another swf which loads your original swf, does the js communication you need and dispatches a KeyboardEvent to the original swf. Worst case scenario you could decompile the original swf which hopefully doesn't have code that is too complex or obfuscated and work from there

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the SWF is your own, in which case you can use the ExternalInterface.call(); method to execute JS directly in the host page, and you can use the ExternalInterface.addCallback() function to register AS functions as callable on the SWF with JS.

[docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to swf's source, it's impossible, as the only way to do this is to register callbacks in flash and call them in JS. Every callback, of course, must use dispatchEvent method to trigger the event you want (or call event-listening function directly).

The only way to solve you problem is to decompile .swf (using Sothink SWF Decompiler, for example). If it's code is not obfuscated, the output code will be enought clear to read and refactor it. Decompile, add callbacks (use ExternalInterface.addCallback()) and compile it a new time.